# How to tell if a character special file would block if read from

Tags: files, io, character-special-files

I would like to be able to tell if a character special file would block if a character were read from it without actually reading a character from it.  Can this be done?

Comment: You will normally need to `open()` the file (though you don't need to `read()` from it).  Will that be a problem?

Comment: Just to clarify my earlier statement - you need an open *file descriptor* to perform this test.  There's no kernel interface to do this with only the *file name* of the device.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this from bash using a 0 timeout to `read`.

```
if read -t 0
then read data
fi
```

To test a file descriptor other than stdin, say 3, use `-u 3`. To find how many chars are ready on stdin you can use a small perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
require 'sys/ioctl.ph';
$size = pack("L", 0);
ioctl(*STDIN, FIONREAD(), $size) or die "ioctl fail: $!\n";
$size = unpack("L", $size);
print "stdin ready: $size\n";
```

Comment: Is `read -t0` guaranteed not to read any characters from stdin, even if there is a line waiting?  I don't find this behaviour documented on the bash or ksh manpages, although `reecho () { read -t1 LINE; echo $LINE; }; echo abcd | reecho` gives the behaviour consistent with what you descibe.

Comment: In my 4.3.42 version the man page says *If TIMEOUT is 0, read returns immediately,
               without trying to read any data,*

Answer (score 7):

POSIX allows non-blocking, zero-character reads which "may detect and return errors", including that the read would block:

- [`open(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) the device in `O_NONBLOCK`ing mode;
- [`read(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) with a count of 0.

If this `read` operation checks for errors in such cases, if a read would block then `read` will return -1 and set `errno` to `EAGAIN` (or possibly `EWOULDBLOCK` for sockets, but you're asking about character devices).

Comment: Thanks.  Can this be done from the shell?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this using the shell, but that doesn't mean it can't be done!

Answer (score 5):

From C or C++ you would normally use `pselect()` to test if there is data ready for reading. You can do that without having to set the file descriptor mode to non-blocking.

Comment: Note that you would set the timeout to 0 seconds and 0 microseconds to do this.  I wondered at first if this meant "zero timeout" or "infinite timeout", but it appears that to get the latter, you pass NULL.

Comment: Nice, I had `pselect()` firmly in the "multiplexing" part of my brain...